# java bilder ли это

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу создать java класс порождающий другие классы.
Этот класс нужен т.к. есть:

1. большое число параметров для конструктора создаваемого объекта среди которых изменяться будут лишь несколько;
2. необходимо производить расчеты каждый раз перед вводом этих параметров в конструктор.

Появились вопросы:

1. Я собираюсь создать отдельный класс, который будет возвращать объекты по команде. Но например в реализации билдера лумбоком появляется вложенный статический класс с билдером. Важно ли как будет реализован класс билдера (отдельный или вложенный статический)?
2. билдеру я собираюсь передавать объекты, которые не пойдут непосредственно на вход конструктора создаваемого класса, а которые будут учувствовать в формировании объектов которые пойдет на вход создаваемого класса. Нормально ли это или обработа данных для подачи их на вход конструктора создаваемого класса это уже не зона ответственности билдера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Патерн реализующий ваш сценарий называется "фабрика".

1. Для билдера loombok делает правильную реализацию.
2. Попробуйте патерн "фабрика" и эти вопросы у вас отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Из того что я прочитал сейчас о фабрике, я понял, что должен быть некий абстрактный класс который по разному реализуется наследниками. Фабрика реализует возврат экземпляра одного из наследников этого абстрактного класса и в этом фишка. Мол один метод может возвращать разные классы... А если мне нет необходимости в абстрактном классе, и я реализую возврат обычного класса, это все равно фабрика?

Comment: сделайте фабрику которая возвращает класс Object, все ваши генерируемые объекты автоматом наследники от Object.

Comment: Т.е. абстрактный класс для фабрики не обязателен, как я понял. Я буду возвращать обычный не абстрактный MyClass и это будет фабрика, как я понял.

Comment: абстрактный не обязательно